# how to connect a microcontroller to internet using a SIM card

Tags: iot, avr, gsm

I have a project at college to make an IOT (Internet Of Things) application, we will use AVR as a microcontroller, the access to internet using a WiFi or Ethernet cable was't very helpful in our application, so we thought that getting access using a SIM card will be much better, is that even possible to do or not?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible. What you need is GSM module like sim 900. You can use USART/UART to communicate with module. It provides a set of [AT commands](https://www.espruino.com/datasheets/SIM900_AT.pdf) which can be used for getting the contents of a web page and posting variables through a GPRS connection.

Various open source libraries are available for Arduino platform. You Can start from there and later write your own code or simply copy the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 3G/GPRS shield. Strictly, any mobile data modem will work, but this is a better search term to use. It should not be too expensive, and will typically operate by sending data (and control information) over a UART serial link. This limits the data rate, but in many applications you probably don't care about data rate.

You might want to check the example software when selecting a modem/shield.

Bear in mind that the various bands are not global, so you need to make sure that whatever you use, it matches your region.